# cmake : error : 'AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW' undeclared

Tags: linux, cmake, raspbian

I am getting following error when compiling cmake.

```
 error: 'AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW' undeclared
```

What is cause of this error please suggest. Is this bug in Raspbian because it is defined in following file `fcntl.h` as per google.
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/fcntl.h#L44

```
[ 37%] Building C object Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/CMakeFiles/cmlibarchive.dir/archive_read_disk_posix.c.o
/home/ignite/rpi_package_sb2/cmake-2.8.10.2/Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/archive_read_disk_posix.c: In function 'tree_current_lstat':
/home/ignite/rpi_package_sb2/cmake-2.8.10.2/Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/archive_read_disk_posix.c:2139:7: error: 'AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/ignite/rpi_package_sb2/cmake-2.8.10.2/Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/archive_read_disk_posix.c:2139:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[2]: *** [Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/CMakeFiles/cmlibarchive.dir/archive_read_disk_posix.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/CMakeFiles/cmlibarchive.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please suggest, what dependencies i have missed related to compilation of cmake ?
I am getting error at make time